# jasmine + karma test runner: how to test window.location.href

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a service that ecapsulate the use of the `window` object:

```
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
    constructor(){};
    get window() : Window {
        return window;
    }
    get href(): string {
        return window.location.href;
    }
    set href(url: string) {
        window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Then I have the following jasmine test:

```
describe('WindowService Test Suite', () => {
    let windowService: WindowService;

    beforeEach(() => { 
        windowService = new WindowService();
    });

    it('should set the href', () => {
        windowService.href = "/test";
        expect(windowService.href).toBe("/test");
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I set the href, the karma redirect to the that url and lead to the others test not being runned.

Any one could give some tip I can test this feature without being redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do simple trick :

```
it('should set the href', () => {
    var currentUrl = windowService.href;
    windowService.href = "#test";
    expect(windowService.href).toBe(currentUrl + "#test");
});
```

the value **#test** will not redirect your page, but will search DIV with id=test to scroll to it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to test this is to have ability to set `window` in `WindowService` via `constructor` or via `setter` to fake object. You can't spy or modify `window.location`...